# SIM800C not registering on network

Tags: networking, sim800

I'm desperately trying to set up the SIM800C controller, but to no avail.

It seems I cannot register on any network. The AT+COPS=? comaand returns:

AT+COPS:",(0-4),(0-2)

I'm trying to figure out what the " means in that return as it's not defined in the documentation?

For those with more experience with this device: Is there anything obvious I may have missed during startup? I have set the baud rate and currently I'm simply powering up the device and setting different frequency bands to test. I worry that there may be some other commands required to get the device in a normal operating mode.

I unfortunately don't have time to work through all the documentation so I thought I would try some experienced folk out there. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I unscrewed the antenna and noticed that both the antenna connector as well as the connector it screws into on the PCB was female. The antenna therefore didn't make contact.

I found a pin, forced a gender swap and the Sim800 registered on the network!